# Disabling Minimize & Maximize On WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize, maximize

WinForms have those three boxes in the upper right hand corner that minimize, maximize, and close the form.  What I want to be able to do is to remove the minimize and maximize, while keeping the close.

I also what to make the close minimize the form instead of closing it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The `Form` has two properties called `MinimizeBox` and `MaximizeBox`, set both of them to `false`.

To stop the form closing, handle the `FormClosing` event, and set `e.Cancel = true;` in there and after that, set `WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;`, to minimize the form.

Comment: Could you not just set control box to false.

Comment: @krystanhonour The OP wanted to keep the close though.

Answer (score 20):

Set `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` form properties to `False`

Answer (score 17):

Bind a handler to the `FormClosing` event, then set `e.Cancel = true`, and set the form `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized`.

If you want to ever actually close  the form, make a class-wide boolean `_close` and, in your handler, set `e.Cancel` to `!_close`, so that whenever the user clicks the `X` on the window, it doesn't close, but you can still close it (without just killing it) with `close = true; this.Close();`

(And just to make my answer complete) set `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` form properties to `False`.

Answer (score 12):

Right Click the form you want to hide them on, choose Controls -> Properties.

In Properties, set

- Control Box -> False
- Minimize Box -> False
- Maximize Box -> False

You'll do this in the designer.

Answer (score 6):

How to make form minimize when closing was already answered, but how to **remove** the minimize and maximize buttons wasn't.
`FormBorderStyle`: `FixedDialog`
`MinimizeBox`: `false`
`MaximizeBox`: `false`

Answer (score 3):

you can simply disable maximize inside form constructor.

```
 public Form1(){
     InitializeComponent();
     MaximizeBox = false;
 }
```

to minimize when closing.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = true;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the form editor select the main form right-click -> properties

Scroll all the way down, find the `MinimiseBox` turn to `False` than same with `MaximiseBox` if you dont want.

[image]

In my case i have just disabled the `MaximiseBox` to `False`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me if you want no border and no maximize (including disable double click maximize over the form) nor minimize:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MaximizeBox = false;
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    this.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
//this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.MaximizeBox = false;
this.MinimizeBox = false;
}
```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55393324/edit) some explanation to your answer

Comment: My friend, it's very easy, only must to read each line of code

Comment: On SO it's low quality answer