# How to add form into tray

Tags: c#, windows

I have a problem. I need to add winform into tray. For example I want to add clock in the tray, to do this I have to add a small winform in the system tray, which will display the time and also will have a small context menu to edit settings etc.

How can I add this form in the system tray? (I tried to search in the internet for any ideas, resolves but anyway I dont have any good idea how to implement this on C#)

Comment: Thanks for advices, but it isn't exactly what I want... I need to add FORM into tray... Or... How I will draw clock etc on notify icon? So... The form must be situated in the system tray and on THIS form I will draw clock, which will be working and showing time and other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows supports adding icons into the tray, whose official name is the notification area. It does not support adding anything else there, so your idea of adding a WinForm is simply not viable.

Comment: Are you serious? So... There are no any variant exists to do my task?

Comment: Yes I am serious. The notification area displays square icons. No other options. One possible option are [deskbands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511446.aspx#deskbands) but MS are telling you not to use those. This may not be what you want to hear, but that doesn't make it any less true I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NotifyIcon object and handle the form resize event to hide the form and display the NotifyIcon.  See  http://alperguc.blogspot.com/2008/11/c-system-tray-minimize-to-tray-with.html and [minimize app to system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625421/minimize-app-to-system-tray).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Windows Forms `NotifyIcon` control.

> Specifies a component that creates an icon in the notification area.

### Check out the description and sample on [MSDN - NotifyIcon Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx).