# After loading my application is not completly hide in tray

Tags: c#, winforms, trayicon

I have code like this:

```
public form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    init(); //read ini and try to minimize
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

and in ini method I minimize form and hide it(in debug i can see form.visible = false), but when it leaves init method then it jumps on timer and change visible = true and i can see my app in taskbar and tray. I want see only tray icon.
I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625421/minimize-app-to-system-tray) to minimize form to tray.

So far i made this,but maybe is implemented wrong way because when form is showed form made something like refresh and it looks strange.

```
private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }

    private void minimizeWindow()//this method is called on form resize
    {
        if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            this.Hide();
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
        else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is simple:

```
        private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }

    private void minimizeWindow()
    {
        if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

and

```
        private void AAL_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minimizeWindow();//call it again
    }
```

Dont use form.ShowInTaskbar = false; because that make many problems.

Answer (score 1):

For hiding the window from task bar you can use `ShowInTaskbar` property. In your `init` method try this thing:

```
form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Comment: when i implemented,it has strange behavior,form is showen and after that is like form refresh.

Comment: @miky can u be more specific. I didnt get what u meant by form refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a minimize event on load, if that your program is set to minimize to system tray!

Or you can add `Me.Opacity = 0`(`Me.Opacity = 1` when clicked on systray icon again) on load, and then hide the taskbar button!