# c# run app, hidden form cant open if I want to

Tags: c#

I have this application witch is auto-hidden. But I cant open it when I want to.
Does someone know how to open a hidden application?

code if have to hide:

```
        protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        this.Visible = false;
    }
```

So, if I run this application, the app completely disappear, not in the taskbar or whatever..

It runs like I want to, but cant open the app when I want to.
Please help!

Comment: Is it a windows forms app?

Comment: if the app is hidden at start. in what condition you want to make it visible?

Comment: @JimVercoelen If it doesn't matter then why don't you start the application minimized instead of hidden? That way you can pull it open from the task bar. Otherwise, look into creating a tray icon or using hotkey combination that you can code to reveal your form.

Comment: @JimVercoelen Fair enough, then a tray icon or hotkey combination is probably the way to go.

Comment: Try a global hook, where you press certain keys at the same time, (for example, `Ctrl+Alt+G`) your unvisible form can show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A possiblity* to design such type of apps is to open them with [ShowInTaskBar = false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showintaskbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [minimize in the system tray](https://alanbondo.wordpress.com/2008/06/22/creating-a-system-tray-app-with-c/). Later on when needed, you can open it up from the system tray. Using this way you have an icon in the system tray, so whenever needed, one can open it up using context menu (given in the example).

Another example to [Minimize in system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625421/minimize-app-to-system-tray).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just for general edumacation:  The actual name of the "system tray" is the Notification Area.