# Windows Application without GUI, only a menu that opens when you right click on the icon on bottom right

Tags: windows, winforms

I'm trying build a Windows Application but i kinda don't know where to start. I'm not really that experienced in windows desktop apps. What i need to do is build an application that is not going to have any graphical user interface but rather work on the background but not like windows services. The user should be able to control what happens in the background via a menu consisting of several options. Something like wampserver. An icon on bottom right, menu pops up when you right click on it. No GUI. I'm looking for experienced developers who can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Derive from [ApplicationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0), then pass your instance of it to `Application.Run()` (instead of a Form). From your custom ApplicationContext you can create and display a [NotifyIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to allow the user an interface in the tray that they can interact with (dynamically create menus for your NotifyIcon and wire up their click events).

Comment: Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909558/2330053) to start from.