# Disable Maximize / Restore button on Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net-cf-3.5

I'm using VC# to develop application on WIN CE env.

1) I would like to have **only** the "X" Button on some of my forms.
2) I want the form to occupy the **full screen**.
3) Form **should not be moved**.
I tried using designer, but was not able to achieve it.

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming Win CE isn't too different to desktop windows, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025923/disabling-minimize-maximize-on-winform?rq=1) answers most of this.  Set the WindowState property to make the form initially maximized.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements

1) have only "X" button on some of my forms 
Set FormBorderStyle, attach your "X" image to right of your top form and implement image Click  event to Close the form.

2) want the form to occupy the full screen
Set WindowState = Maximized

3) Forms should not be moved
Not sure why you want to do that , you can use ShowModal/TopMost to ask user to remind user on the input , but not putting glue on the form and kind of un-user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply utilize the following lines

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```