# how to disable maximize button on c# form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

How do I disable the maximize button on a C# form?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Minimize & Maximize On WinForm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025923/disabling-minimize-maximize-on-winform)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `MaximizeBox` to false

```
this.MaximizeBox = false;//this is an instance of Form or its decendant
```

Comment: yes, you are correct. Sorry for my eng. I live in not englishspeakin country

Comment: Looks like Ukrainan isnt't it?

Comment: It looks like Ukrainan but its russian

Answer (score 0):

Simply Change Settings in **Properties** -
 **MaximizeBox** --> **false**;