# how to prevent none state form from being maximized in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, maximize, maximize-window, formborderstyle

i have created a form and set its `FormBorderStyle` property to `none`.
when i press `Windows + UP` form will be **Maximized**. how can i prevent form from maximize?
i tried

```
private void logIn_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
```

but its not that i want. with above code when i press `Windows + Up` form will maximize and then it restores to normal state. but i want to prevent it basically.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025923/disabling-minimize-maximize-on-winform help?

Comment: @Hans You might consider taking a closer look at it (for bug or something) because nothing seem to prevent that behavior when `FormBorderStyle.None`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the form's MaximizeBox to False *should* be enough to stop this Aero Snap feature.  But Form.CreateParams calculates the wrong style flags for some mysterious reason.  I can't single-step it right now due to the 4.7.1 update and don't see the mistake in the source code.  It might have something to do with disabling it in the system menu but not the style flags, just a guess.

Anyhoo, hammering the native style flag off by force does solve the problem.  Copy-paste this code into your form class:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style &= ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Define the border style of the form to a dialog box.
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

// Set the MaximizeBox to false to remove the maximize box.
form1.MaximizeBox = false;

// Set the MinimizeBox to false to remove the minimize box.
form1.MinimizeBox = false;
```

Credit to [How do I disable form resizing for users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416380/how-do-i-disable-form-resizing-for-users)

Comment: i want a form with formBorderStyle.none

Comment: Im sure there are multiple ways to do it but that is what i have shown. `FixedDialog` will stop manual resizing. `MaximiseBox = False` stops you from maximising the window and `MinimiseBox = False` should do the same for minimising.